# Azure Devops Build/Release - all configs included except appSettings.config

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, appsettings

The project I am working on is a API App service.  It builds and deploys fine, but it will not run correctly due to the appSettings.config file not being transferred over.  It appears to not be included in the .zip file that is dropped in the artifacts.  I have tried setting it to copy always, messing with the csproj file, etc, but no luck.  Config files such as the Web.config and unity.config are carried over, but the appSettings.config is not.  I can copy it over later, but that defeats the purpose as I want to use the XML substitution.  Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Devops Build/Release - all configs included except appSettings.config

To keep `appsettings.json` to be left beside the published app, you could try to set the property `<ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>` for this `appsettings.json` file in the project file .csproj.

Check [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/7738) for some more details.

Hope this helps.